# Get AAR version programmatically

Tags: android, aar

I am creating an `AAR` library, In the arr `manifest` we have `version` name, and version code. How can I get this version. I don't want the main app version. I just want the library version.

Is there a way to get this version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Define those values as resources.

Step #2: Adjust your manifest to reference those resources.

Step #3: Refer to those values from the rest of your app via those resources.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. but now version is set from build.gradle file.. how will i reference strings value from build.gradle

Comment: @ShrikanthKalluraya: Define a constant in the `build.gradle` file (or in `gradle.properties`). Use that both for your version information and for `resConfig` statements that defines the resources. Or, use the constant for `buildConfigField` statements that add fields to `BuildConfig`, if you only need to refer to the values in Java code.

Comment: Can I use BuildConfig to define app version in build.gradle? Sorry I have never done this. I want same value to be used in java and build.gradle. Can you please guide me?

Comment: No, but you can use the same value in build.gradle (or gradle.properties) to fill in both buildConfigField and versionCode, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there perhaps some gradle trick to get the dependency version, so that you could get it at runtime? Something that could even work when you write it in the Android-library itself? I asked about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70460845/878126

Answer (score 0):

I just tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47807652/7208790) on our AAR libraries and it is working fine to get the versionName and versionCode defined in the build.gradle of your AAR lib. It appears to be the easiest solution. Basically:

Use `String libVersionName = your.lib.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;`

or in your library, just use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` to get it.

For versionCode, use: `int libVersionCode = your.lib.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;`